# New to Python: Why do I get the error ImportError: cannot import name 'SetWindowPos' from 'win32con'

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com, win32gui

I am trying to put together some code that will pin the pygame window to the front - after doing some research I think the simplest way to do this in python 3.9 is is with

```
import win32gui
from win32con import SetWindowPos

SetWindowPos(pygame.display.get_wm_info()['window'], win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 0,0,0,0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
```

but I consistently get the error message

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SetWindowPos' from 'win32con'
```

Anyone know why/how to fix this?

I've tried updating pip and making sure that my version of python and pip are compatable. I've tried the following commands:

```
python -m pip install pywin32
```

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

```
pip install win32con
```

I am not sure if this matters but I also installed win32gui and kept getting the error message

```
subprocess-exited-with-error
```

regardless of how many times I updated pip/python and made sure they were compatable

Comment: `win32con` contains constants, not functions.  You should use `win32gui.SetWindowPos`.